# Window output redirection to a file should be appended rather than re creation

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have an exe and I am redirecting the output as follows.

```
mastercore.exe > D:\\Output.txt
```

or

```
mastercore.exe dir > D:\\Output.txt
```

The problem is the output.txt is recreated each time I start the command. I want the output.txt to be appended, rather. Can someone please suggest how this can be done?

Comment: `>` overwrites, `>>` appends

Comment: For details read the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use double >>:

```
mastercore.exe >> D:\\Output.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, I realized it just after I posted.